# How do I stay in VR when linking between mobile WebVR sites in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

I am linking between several WebVR experiences on a mobile WebVR site. When I use the cursor component or another component to navigate to another site, it loads the next site in mono mode (not VR).

How do I stay in VR for mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we improve the link traversal story, this will become better out of the box for mobile. Note this answer is for mobile, desktop/true WebVR will have link traversal as part of the spec and will become part of A-Frame in the future as browser support rolls out.

But on mobile, you should be able to enter stereo mode without requiring user interaction. Though I forget whether on some devices we are using the fullscreen API so that might get in the way.

Here's a component to automatically persist VR:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('auto-enter-vr', {
  init: function () {
    this.el.sceneEl.enterVR();
  }
});
```

Then you can use it like:

```
<a-scene auto-enter-vr>
```

Check out the `href` component to add links (e.g., change window.location on event such as cursor component click).

Comment: Some users have reported getting: `Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.`. Is that specific to iOS or Android, and can they opt out of using full-screen API?